# ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type:

Tags: sql, linux, database, oracle, plsql

Help please, is there something wrong with my references?
It showing ERROR like this :

> ERROR at line 10:
> ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type

[image: click to show error image 1]

Comment: Error seems pretty clear. What are the datatypes?

Comment: `STUDENT.NIM` is a `NUMBER(10)`. `STUDYPLAN.NIM` is a `VARCHAR2(15)`. If you want these to have a foreign key relation, they have to be the same datatype

Comment: I have done created `3 tables`, now then when I creating a reference table, i got an error like the picture `TABLE 4`

Comment: TABLE 1 = https://jmp.sh/GUC4Skr

Comment: TABLE 2 = https://jmp.sh/Y3DtxgR

Comment: TABLE 3 = https://jmp.sh/l2EEYMn

Comment: TABLE 4 REFERENCE ERROR = https://jmp.sh/eMePHW9

Comment: I've tried to change `STUDY_PLAN.NIM` . `STUDY_PLAN.NIP` . `STUDY_PLAN.KMK` to `NUMBER(10)` but it seems there is still an error sir,@HoneyBadger - https://jmp.sh/pgUarOT

Comment: It is still the same kind of error. Still different datatypes, just different columns. And please don't assume my gender, I haven't told you if I am a "sir" or otherwise

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE STUDY_PLAN (
  NIM number(10) not null,
  NIP number(15) not null,
  KMK varchar2(10) not null,
  UTS number(4),
  UAS number(4),
  IPK number(4),
  KELAS varchar2(4),
  TAHUN_AJAR varchar2(50),
    CONSTRAINT F_NIM FOREIGN KEY(NIM) REFERENCES STUDENT,
    CONSTRAINT F_NIP FOREIGN KEY(NIP) REFERENCES LECTURER(NIP),
    CONSTRAINT F_KDMK FOREIGN KEY(KMK) REFERENCES COURSE)
/
```

solved with this qode, thanks all